# Prove function under subspace topology

Tags: real-analysis

In a topological space $X$, $Y\subset X$ is the subspace topology and their Borel $\sigma$-algebras. Show that $f \upharpoonright_Y$ is measurable if $f:X\rightarrow Z$ is ($Z$ is a measurable space).

Comment: Take $B=f^{-1}(E)$ where $E$ is a Borel set in $Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE ^_^

Hint:

To show that $f \upharpoonright_Y$ is measurable, it suffices to show that

$$(f \upharpoonright_Y)^{-1} (E) = \{ y \in Y ~|~ (f \upharpoonright_Y)(y) \in E \}$$

is borel (in $Y$) for every $E \subseteq Z$ measurable.

But we know that

$$f^{-1}(E) = \{ x \in X ~|~ f(x) \in E \}$$

is measurable because that's the definition of $f : X \to Z$ being measurable.

- Can you show that $(f \upharpoonright_Y)^{-1} (E) = f^{-1}(E) \cap Y$?
- Can you use this to show that $(f \upharpoonright_Y)^{-1} (E)$ is indeed borel in $Y$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: For the first, you might want to look at the definition of the sets shown in my answer. Remember that $(f \upharpoonright_Y)y = f(y)$ and see if you can use that to show both directions at once. For the second, you're on the exact right track! If you can show that $f^{-1}(E)$ is borel in $X$, then you're done. Thankfully, $f : X \to Z$ is measurable. What does that tell you?

Comment: There's a few ways to show that. The idea is that the borel sets are generated by the open sets. But the open sets of $Y$ are exactly $U \cap Y$ for some open set $U$ of $X$.